# change the number of digits in a number within a string

Tags: r, regex

I have a set of strings, which all have numbers with 4 digits, e.g.:

"FTMS + c NSI Full ms [364.0000-391.0000]"

I would like to convert all the numbers  to have only 2 digits, so that it becomes

"FTMS + c NSI Full ms [364.00-391.00]"

the strings do not have a specific structure. Is there a simple one line solution?

Comment: This is easy, you just define a capture group which only matches the part of the string/number you want to keep, followed by extra regex parts to match the parts you want to drop. As @Gregor showed. When you say *"the strings do not have a specific structure"*, what do you mean? Do you mean "the trailing digits have different (non-zero) values" or "there are (say) between 2-6 trailing digits"? in which case you're simply asking "what is a regex that matches a digit" `[0-9]` or "2-6 digits"? `[0-9]{2,6}`

Comment: My assumption about what OP means with "do not have a specific structure" is that there might be different words /different number of words before (and after?) brackets with numbers in them, maybe multiple numbers, maybe not always brackets... But it is strange to say there is not specific structure but not give *any* examples of the variability. But the regex solution provided doesn't make any assumptions other than what OP does definitively state.

Comment: sorry to not be clearer on the word structure. The number of digits is consistent in all numbers, however the position of a number can be anywhere within a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### gsubfn

This uses only a simple pattern that matches character strings representing a number having decimals converting each such match to numeric and using `sprintf` to format with 2 decimals.

```
library(gsubfn)

gsubfn("\\d+\\.\\d+", ~ sprintf("%.2f", as.numeric(x)), s)
## [1] "FTMS + c NSI Full ms [364.00-391.00]"
```

### Base R

A base solution would be to match the part to be kept followed by the remaining digits and then keep only the part to be kept.

```
gsub("(\\d+\\.\\d{2})\\d+", "\\1", s)
## [1] "FTMS + c NSI Full ms [364.00-391.00]"
```

### Note

The input is:

```
s <- "FTMS + c NSI Full ms [364.0000-391.0000]"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! you actually answered what I wanted, not what I asked. I need the gsubfn() solution since I dont want to just change the number of digits by dropping extra digits, but instead round to certain precision.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
library(stringr)

x = "FTMS + c NSI Full ms [364.0000-391.0000]"

str_replace_all(x, "([0-9]+\\.[0-9]{2})[0-9]+", "\\1")
# [1] "FTMS + c NSI Full ms [364.00-391.00]"
```

We look for patterns of

- First capturing group: 1 or more numbers, followed by "." followed by exactly 2 numbers
- followed by more numbers

We match everything described above, and replace it with the first capturing group (first bullet).